# Select next / previous Kivy RecycleView row on button press

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing a Kivy media player and using the RecycleView to display my media list.

What I am attempting to achieve is to change the existing row selection to either the next or previous row in the RecycleView list from a button selection.

I can see the [LayoutSelectionBehavior](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/recycleview/layout.html) class looks like the appropriate method but I am struggling to find an approach to use this.

Below is a simplified example of the RecycleView modified from the [kivy.uix.recycleview](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) examples

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty 
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior


kv = """

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1) if self.selected else (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<KivyPlayer>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:  
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                id: next_track
                text: "Next Track"
            Button:
                id: previous_track
                text: "Previous Track"
        BoxLayout:
            RecycleView:
                id: media_list
                viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
                scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
                scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
                bar_width: dp(10)
                SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None, dp(56)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    # multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
                    spacing: dp(2)


"""

Builder.load_string(kv)

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class KivyPlayer(BoxLayout):
    ''' Main Kivy class for creating the initial BoxLayout '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyPlayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

       # Set media_list data
        self.ids.media_list.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class KivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KivyPlayer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KivyApp().run()
```

Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it'd be nice if we add a get_next/previous_node, perhaps in the future. Anyway, here's what you do.

Modify the buttons so:

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        id: next_track
        text: "Next Track"
        on_release: controller.select_next()
    Button:
        id: previous_track
        text: "Previous Track"
        on_release: controller.select_previous()
```

And edit the `SelectableRecycleBoxLayout` in kv as follows:

```
SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
    id: controller
    key_selection: 'selectable'
```

Finally, here's what `SelectableRecycleBoxLayout` should look like:

```
class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    def get_nodes(self):
        nodes = self.get_selectable_nodes()
        if self.nodes_order_reversed:
            nodes = nodes[::-1]
        if not nodes:
            return None, None

        selected = self.selected_nodes
        if not selected:  # nothing selected, select the first
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
            return None, None

        if len(nodes) == 1:  # the only selectable node is selected already
            return None, None

        last = nodes.index(selected[-1])
        self.clear_selection()
        return last, nodes

    def select_next(self):
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if last == len(nodes) - 1:
            self.select_node(nodes[0])
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last + 1])

    def select_previous(self):
        last, nodes = self.get_nodes()
        if not nodes:
            return

        if not last:
            self.select_node(nodes[-1])
        else:
            self.select_node(nodes[last - 1])
```

You also need to specify in the data what should be selectable as follows: `self.ids.media_list.data = [{'text': str(x), 'selectable': True} for x in range(100)]` (note, you forgot the `ids` part in your example).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read this post and provide such a detailed response @matt. Your solution is working perfectly. I'll read up on the use of `ids` as I've not seen that before.

SO moderators, unsure on the policy for asking additional questions in replies so apologies if I should post a new question.

@matt is there an easy way of selecting the first/next node from the init method of KivyPlayer class? Happy to discuss in #kivy IRC if you have a handle there?

Comment: I have found a hacky approach which is to use the ButtonBehavior class and trigger_action method `self.next_track.trigger_action(duration=0.1)` I suspect there is a cleaner way :)

Comment: You do need to use the clock for this. But something like `Clock.schedule_once(lambda *x: self.ids.controller.select_node(0), 0.1)`. But you should ask on IRC if it doesn't work (I'm `matham` there too).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks again for the reply!